# network problems

Tags: switch, router, ospf, troubleshooting

I am having a problem with my network. I have a router (R1) connected to another router (R2) R1 is connected to a switch. R1 switch has two PC's connected to it. the PC IP's are 128.107.35.10 and 192.31.7.10. The default gateway is 198.133.220.1. when i ping from the R1 PC's i get request timed out. when i ping from R2 PC's i get destination host unreachable. I have OSPF and RIP v2 on both routers.
Does anyone know why this is happening?

**Show ip route R1**

```
  10.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 3 subnets, 2 masks

R       10.0.0.0/8 [120/1] via 198.133.219.1, 00:00:09, Serial0/0/0

O       10.255.1.0/30 [110/192] via 198.133.219.1, 00:19:49, Serial0/0/0

O       10.255.1.4/30 [110/128] via 198.133.219.1, 00:19:49, Serial0/0/0

     192.168.20.0/24 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
R       192.168.20.0/24 [120/1] via 198.133.219.1, 00:00:09, Serial0/0/0

O       192.168.20.0/30 [110/128] via 198.133.219.1, 00:19:49, Serial0/0/0

     192.168.21.0/30 is subnetted, 1 subnets
O       192.168.21.0 [110/256] via 198.133.219.1, 00:19:49, Serial0/0/0

     198.133.219.0/24 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C       198.133.219.0/30 is directly connected, Serial0/0/0

C       198.133.219.1/32 is directly connected, Serial0/0/0

     198.133.220.0/27 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C       198.133.220.0 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/1
```

**Show IP route for R2**

```
     10.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 5 subnets, 4 masks

C       10.10.10.64/27 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/1

R       10.10.10.96/28 [120/1] via 10.255.1.2, 00:00:20, Serial0/1/0

C       10.255.1.0/30 is directly connected, Serial0/1/0

C       10.255.1.4/30 is directly connected, Serial0/0/0

C       10.255.1.5/32 is directly connected, Serial0/0/0
     192.168.20.0/24 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
R       192.168.20.0/24 [120/1] via 10.255.1.5, 00:00:28, Serial0/0/0

O       192.168.20.0/30 [110/128] via 10.255.1.5, 00:28:51, Serial0/0/0
     192.168.21.0/30 is subnetted, 1 subnets
O       192.168.21.0 [110/128] via 10.255.1.2, 00:28:51, Serial0/1/0

     198.133.219.0/24 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
R       198.133.219.0/24 [120/1] via 10.255.1.5, 00:00:28, Serial0/0/0

O       198.133.219.0/30 [110/128] via 10.255.1.5, 00:24:26, Serial0/0/0

     198.133.220.0/24 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
R       198.133.220.0/24 [120/2] via 10.255.1.5, 00:00:28, Serial0/0/0

O IA    198.133.220.0/27 [110/129] via 10.255.1.5, 00:24:16, Serial0/0/0
```

**Start up config for R1**

```
!
version 12.4

no service timestamps log datetime msec

no service timestamps debug datetime msec

no service password-encryption
!

hostname internet

!
!
!
enable secret 5 REMOVED

enable password REMOVED

!
!
!
!
!
!
no ip cef

no ipv6 cef

!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
no ip domain-lookup

!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst

!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0

 no ip address

 duplex auto

 speed auto

 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0/1

 ip address 198.133.220.1 255.255.255.224

 duplex auto

 speed auto

!
interface Serial0/0/0

 ip address 198.133.219.2 255.255.255.252

 encapsulation ppp

!
interface Serial0/0/1

 no ip address

 clock rate 2000000

 shutdown

!
interface Serial0/1/0

 no ip address

 clock rate 2000000

 shutdown

!

interface Serial0/1/1

 no ip address

 clock rate 2000000

 shutdown

!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
router ospf 1

 log-adjacency-changes

 network 198.133.219.0 0.0.0.3 area 0

 network 10.255.1.4 0.0.0.3 area 0

 network 10.255.1.0 0.0.0.3 area 0

 network 192.168.20.0 0.0.0.3 area 0

 network 192.168.21.0 0.0.0.3 area 0

 network 10.10.10.0 0.0.0.3 area 0

 network 10.255.0.0 0.0.0.3 area 0

 network 10.10.10.64 0.0.0.15 area 51

 network 10.10.10.96 0.0.0.15 area 51

 network 10.10.10.0 0.0.0.15 area 51

 network 198.133.220.0 0.0.0.15 area 51

!
router rip

 version 2

 network 10.0.0.0

 network 192.168.20.0

 network 192.168.21.0

 network 198.133.219.0

 network 198.133.220.0

!
ip classless

!
ip flow-export version 9

!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

**Start up config for R2**

```
!
version 12.4

no service timestamps log datetime msec

no service timestamps debug datetime msec

service password-encryption
!
hostname south
!
!
!
enable secret 5 REMOVED

enable password 7 REMOVED

!
!
ip dhcp excluded-address 10.10.10.65

!
ip dhcp pool South

 network 10.10.10.64 255.255.255.224

 default-router 10.10.10.65

ip dhcp pool LAN

 network 10.10.10.64 255.255.255.224

 default-router 10.10.10.65

!

!
!
no ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
no ip domain-lookup

!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst

!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0

 no ip address

 duplex auto

 speed auto

 shutdown

!
interface FastEthernet0/1

 ip address 10.10.10.65 255.255.255.224

 duplex auto

 speed auto

!
interface Serial0/0/0

 ip address 10.255.1.6 255.255.255.252

 encapsulation ppp

 clock rate 128000

!
interface Serial0/0/1

 no ip address

 clock rate 2000000

 shutdown

!
interface Serial0/1/0

 ip address 10.255.1.1 255.255.255.252

 clock rate 128000

!
interface Serial0/1/1

 no ip address

 clock rate 2000000

!
interface Vlan1

 no ip address

 shutdown

!
router ospf 1

 log-adjacency-changes

 network 10.255.1.0 0.0.0.3 area 0

 network 198.133.219.0 0.0.0.3 area 0

 network 192.168.20.0 0.0.0.3 area 0

 network 10.255.1.4 0.0.0.3 area 0

 network 10.255.0.0 0.0.0.3 area 0

 network 10.10.10.0 0.0.0.15 area 51

 network 198.133.220.0 0.0.0.15 area 51

!
router rip

 version 2

 network 10.0.0.0

 network 192.168.20.0

 network 198.133.219.0

 network 198.133.220.0

!
ip classless

!
ip flow-export version 9

!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

Comment: Please provide relevant parts of your configurations and routing tables for these routers, without those we'll not be able to help you.

Comment: Next time you might want to remove passwords from your output

Comment: I don't want to make too many assumptions about your network, so lets start with some basics:  What address are you pinging?   Can your PCs ping their default gateways?  PC#2 seems to have an address that is not in any subnet on your router.  Is that correct?

Comment: I am pinging from 10.10.10.66 to either 128.107.35.10/192.31.7.10, when i do this i get destination host unreachable. 128.107.35.10/192.31.7.10 are intended to represent public ip address. When i ping 128.107.35.10/192.31.7.10 default gateway i get request timed out.

Comment: Your R1 hosts aren't in the same network as their default gateway. Your switch of your source doesn't know how to route to your destinations either...

Comment: Your subject is much too wide to get a correct analysis. Many network engineer won't even open it. Would you open a question titled "Is Internet down?"?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not a lot of info here, but here goes...

You cannot have a PC with an IP address of 128.107.33.10 and a PC with an IP address of 192.31.7.10 use a default gateway of 198.133.220.1/27.  Most operating systems will complain that the default gateway is not within the same network as the PC, but then I have no idea of the netmask on your PCs.  You have two easy options (without changing the config on R2 or using a massive subnet mask that encompasses both PCs):

Option 1:

If you absolutely MUST keep the same IP addresses on the PCs...
You change the primary IP address on the FastEthernet 1 interface on R1 to be in the same network as the first PC and add a secondary IP address to the FastEthernet 1 to match the networks as defined on the second PC.  You would then need to add these networks into RIP and/or OSPF to distribute them to R2 (if you use both, the OSPF routes will show up and the RIP ones will be ignored, but that will still be OK).

Option 2:

You change the PCs to be in the range of 198.133.220.2 to 198.133.220.14 with the netmask 255.255.255.224.  You will also need to add a network statement to RIP and/or OSPF to advertise the 198.133.220.0/27 network.

You are also best to change the serial interface that is connected between R1 and R2 to have both sides in the same subnet (though as it is, the magical PPP may make this work, it is not recommended and traceroutes will look strange).  I would also not run two routing protocols for no real reason and I would tidy the entire thing up (it needs a network redesign!), but I am assuming there are good reasons for this.

-- Ben

Answer (score -1):

You have no interfaces on your router?  They should show up in the show run or write term output.  In any case, you need to enable a routing protocol or code in static routes.  It is a routing issue.  I do not see RIP configured in your output.  Configure RIPv2 if you would like.  Documentation is online.

ADDED----

Try adding
 
no auto-summarize
redistribute connected

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/ip/configuration/guide/fipr_c/1cfrip.html